# How does oracle (via sql/plus) determine the charset used to evaluate a sql script

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to have a few details about how oracle (via sql/plus) determine the charset used to evaluate a sql script.

My database is configured like this:

```
select VALUE from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';
VALUE
------
WE8ISO8859P15
```

The problem is that I read here http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/NLS that session parameters could take precedence over database parameters.

Does it mean that database encoding is overriden by the one defined in the NLS_LANG environment variable of the user who executes the script?

Apparently, it's not possible to modify the encoding in a script via an alter session statement.

I'm asking this question since I already had a problem of corrupted characters with a production script executed by a subcontractor in India. I actually don't know if it was because he did something wrong with my file (like copy/paste in a sql gui client) or if it was because of his environment.

To summarize my actual problem, will everything be OK if

- The user is configured with a charset of UTF8
- My sql file is encoded in UTF8
- My database is in WE8ISO8859P15

Thank's in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The Oracle Client always converts between the database characterset and the characterset of the client machine, which is determined by the NLS_LANG environment variable or the system settings.

Please note that UTF8 supports only Unicode version 3.1 and earlier. Use AL32UTF8 instead to get full Unicode support.

Comment: Thank you for this precision, I will precise this on my request although I don't think it would be a problem for a script containing only latin1 characters (French).